# Can I add a subclass after already instantiating the parent class?

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have two classes `Foo` and `Bar`. Is it possible to instantiate `Foo` and then add `Bar` as a subclass after? In other words, instead of calling `foo = Foo(Bar)`, can I do something like `foo = Foo()` and then `foo.add_subclass(Bar)` and have the resulting class be the same things as `Foo(Bar)`?

To give a specific example of why I would want to do this is with SQLalchemy. In particular, the following adds a table, to a database:

```
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base as Base

base = Base()

class Table(base):
    __tablename__ = "table"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    row = db.Column(db.String(50))
    def __init__(
        self,
        row_stuff,
    ):
        self.row = row_stuff

engine = db.create_engine(...)
base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

However, I would like to keep `Table` as a template in some file, `template.py` and then add `base` to it at a later time. I would like to do something like this:

```
from template import Table
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base as Base

table = Table
base = Base()
table.add_base = base

engine = db.create_engine(...)

table.base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

Comment: this is incorrect design. Look at DeclarativeBase arrangement https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.DeclarativeBase

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thanks, I see where I was wrong, this also helped to clear it up https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html

Answer (score -1):

What you are doing looks like you would be ok with just having `base` be a property of `Table`. Since you aren't trying to call `Table`'s methods or access `Table`'s properties from `base` (there's no inheritance involved), and are instead trying to call `base`'s methods as a child of table (`table.base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)`), you can write a function like this:

```py
class Table:
  ...
  def add_base(self, base):
    table.base = base
```

Then you can do as you wished:

```py
table = Table()
base = Base()
...
table.add_base(base)
```

alternatively, just do

```py
table.base = base
```

From there, you can run lines like `table.base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)` with no problems, just using `base` as a child of `Table`.